# TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element Conditional based data-testid in @testing-library/react

Tags: unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-testing

I have written many test cases in the react testing library, I got stuck in the accessing condition based DOM element. I have tried many ways using import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'. But didn't work from me. Here is the code. Great appreciate

```
import axios from "axios";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

function MDStaticContent({ t }) {
const [promoArrayIsValid, setPromoArrayIsValid] = useState(false);

const loadRecent = async () => {
    API Calls Here
    const recents = await onRecentMedia(accounts[0], instance);

    if (Some condition) {
      if (Here Some condition) {
        setPromoArrayIsValid(true);
      }
      dispatch(Here Will discpatch data);
    }
  };

return (
    <>
      { promoArrayIsValid && (
        <div data-testid="mdStaticContent">
        Hello
    </div>
 </>
      )}
}


import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import MDStaticContent from "./MDStaticContent";
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import MockAPIData from '../resources/locales/en/MockAPIData.json';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'


const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
let data = {
  mediaArrayIsValid: true,
  promoArrayIsValid: true
}
const store = mockStore(data);


it("should take a snapshot and match of MDStaticContent Page", () => {
  const { asFragment, getAllByTestId, getByTestId
 } = render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MemoryRouter>
              <MDStaticContent/>
            </MemoryRouter>
        </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();

expect(getAllByTestId("mdStaticContent")).toHaveLength(1);
expect(getByTestId("mdStaticContent")).toBeVisible();

});
```

[image]

Comment: Is `promoArrayIsValid` truthy when your component is rendered?

Comment: @tromgy Initial it will false, once API scuess it becomes true. Based on that DOM will get loaded { promoArrayIsValid && (
        <div data-testid="mdStaticContent">
  Hello
 </div>
      )}
I want to Set promoArrayIsValid True while writing unit test cases.

Comment: It looks like you're using it as both the prop and the state, then set the initial value of the state from the prop. Set it to `true` in the test, and to `false` in the product.

Comment: @tromgy Just I tried possible ways passting props and set. Seems props is not required. I have updated the code by removing props.

Comment: @tromgy I want to know How to set values of useState in Test cases.

Comment: In general, you should avoid testing the internal workings of your component. If the only way the state changes is through some server interaction, try to mock the server side. You can use for example [MSW](https://github.com/mswjs/msw) for that.